# Can I render a region of my drupal site on a non-drupal site?

Tags: theming

Here is my situation.

I'm in the process of implementing Drupal as the primary CMS for a large site with hundreds of pages. But until the data input into Drupal can be done (which will be an ongoing process over months), I'd like the older "non-drupal" pages to at least be faked into looking like they are part of the same site. Basically I just want to tack onto the old pages, the new drupal header and footer (which are independent regions).

I was wondering if there is a known way to show a region from your drupal site on a regular php page? Such as a simple drupal "region rendering function" or something?

ps. The navigation has dropdown menus so iframes are out of the question.

Any constructive insight into how I should approach this would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: It's technically possible (as all things are) but it's not a simple job, and it would be horribly inefficient. You'd have to 1. bootstrap Drupal fully, 2. invoke its menu handler for a path relevant enough to give you the correct HTML (active menu paths, etc), 3. Perform the full page render, bypassing the normal page delivery methods, 4. Extract the regions you're interested in from the render array and display them. Trying to shoehorn one website into another is never going to be a good idea I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Web Widgets](https://drupal.org/project/web_widgets) module to embed.

> Create dynamic snippets of your Drupal site that users can copy and
>   paste to their websites.
>
> - Supported widget styles: iframe, inline, UWA or Google Gadgets.
> - Build a view and make a widget from it.
> - Embed any other web site content in a widget with a simple widget API.

also look in to [Embed widgets](https://drupal.org/project/embed_widgets) module.